# Не работает try catch

Tags: java

Не работает try catch. В чем моя ошибка? Задан массив типа Byte из 5-ти элемнтов. Элементы вводятся вручную. Необходимо вывести ошибку, если их сумма выходит за пределы типа Byte.

```java
try {
  for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    y += x[i];
  }
  
  if ((y > 128) || (y < -127)) {
    throw new InputMismatchException();
  }
}
catch(InputMismatchException ex) {
  System.err.println("Сумма элементов выходит за границы типа Byte");
}
```

Comment: С виду код правильный. А что в `x`?

Comment: Код не полон - гадаем: тип `y` `byte`, поэтому сумма никогда не выходит из диапазона для байта. Если угадал, то сделайте тип `int`.

Comment: Благодарю. Ваш способ работает.